# Crash related to boost::function usage in thread pool

Tags: c++, pthreads, threadpool, boost-bind, boost-function

I am trying to implement thread pool in C++ using pthread. I want to encapsulate logic related to threads management in one object which is taking ownership of these threads. That means whenever this object is destroyed, threads must be stopped and cleaned up.

I've been testing my code and it turns out that I get segmentation fault when I destroy WorkerThreadManager object while there is boost::function called. See the code and backtrace from GDB. I don't really understand why it happens, as far as I know boost::function is copyable, so once I get a copy of it from the queue, I can pop() it and even destroy whole queue (I prooved that in some small test) and then call the function's copy.

WorkerThreadManager.h:

```
#include "WorkerThreadManagerInterface.h"
#include "utils/mutex.h"
#include <queue>
#include <semaphore.h>

#include <iostream>

class WorkerThreadManager : public WorkerThreadManagerInterface
{
    public:
        WorkerThreadManager(unsigned threadsNumber = 5);
        virtual ~WorkerThreadManager();

        virtual void    PushTask(thread_function_t A_threadFun, result_function_t A_resultFun);
        void    SignalResults();

    private:
        static void*    WorkerThread(void* A_data);

        void    PushResult(int A_result, result_function_t A_resultFun);

        typedef boost::function<void ()> signal_function_t;

        struct worker_thread_data_t
        {
            worker_thread_data_t(thread_function_t A_threadFun, result_function_t A_resultFun) :
                threadFun(A_threadFun), resultFun(A_resultFun) {}
            worker_thread_data_t() {}

            thread_function_t       threadFun;
            result_function_t       resultFun;
        };


        const unsigned                      m_threadsNumber;
        pthread_t*                          m_pthreads;

        utils::Mutex                        m_tasksMutex;
        sem_t                               m_tasksSem;
        std::queue<worker_thread_data_t>    m_tasks;

        utils::Mutex                        m_resultsMutex;
        std::queue<signal_function_t>       m_results;
};
```

WorkerThreadManager.cpp:

```
#include "WorkerThreadManager.h"
#include "gateway_log.h"
#include <pthread.h>

/**
 * @brief Creates semaphore and starts threads.
 */
WorkerThreadManager::WorkerThreadManager(unsigned threadsNumber) : m_threadsNumber(threadsNumber)
{
    if ( sem_init(&m_tasksSem, 0, 0) )
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "Semaphore could not be initialized: " << errno << " - " << strerror(errno);
        LOG_FATAL(ss);
        throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
    }

    m_pthreads = new pthread_t[m_threadsNumber];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < m_threadsNumber; ++i)
    {
        int rc = pthread_create(&m_pthreads[i], NULL, WorkerThreadManager::WorkerThread, (void*) this );
        if(rc)
        {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << "Pthread could not be started: " << errno << " - " << strerror(errno);
            LOG_FATAL(ss.str());

            if ( sem_destroy(&m_tasksSem) )
                LOG_ERROR("Semaphore could not be destroyed: " << errno << " - " << strerror(errno));

            delete [] m_pthreads;

            throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
        }
        else
        {
            LOG_DEBUG("Worker thread started " << m_pthreads[i]);

            if(pthread_detach(m_pthreads[i]))
                LOG_WARN("Failed to detach worker thread");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Cancels all threads, destroys semaphore
 */
WorkerThreadManager::~WorkerThreadManager()
{
    LOG_DEBUG("~WorkerThreadManager()");

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < m_threadsNumber; ++i)
    {
        if ( pthread_cancel(m_pthreads[i]) )
            LOG_ERROR("Worker thread cancellation failed");
    }

    if ( sem_destroy(&m_tasksSem) )
        LOG_ERROR("Semaphore could not be destroyed: " << errno << " - " << strerror(errno));

    delete [] m_pthreads;
}

/**
 * @brief Adds new task to queue, so worker threads can
 * @param A_threadFun function which will be executed by thread
 * @param A_resultFun function which will be enqueued for calling with return value of A_threadFun as parameter
 *          after worker thread executes A_threadFun.
 */
void WorkerThreadManager::PushTask(thread_function_t A_threadFun, result_function_t A_resultFun)
{
    utils::ScopedLock mutex(m_tasksMutex);

    worker_thread_data_t    data(A_threadFun, A_resultFun);
    m_tasks.push( data );
    sem_post(&m_tasksSem);
    LOG_DEBUG("Task for worker threads has been added to queue");
}

/**
 * @brief   Executes result functions (if there are any) to give feedback 
 *  to classes which requested task execution in worker thread.
 */
void WorkerThreadManager::SignalResults()
{
    while(true)
    {
        signal_function_t signal;
        {
            utils::ScopedLock mutex(m_resultsMutex);
            if(m_results.size())
            {
                signal = m_results.front();
                m_results.pop();
            }
            else
                return;
        }

        signal();
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Enqueues result of function executed in worker thread.
 * @param A_result return value of function executed in worker thread
 * @param A_resultFun function which will be enqueued for calling with A_result as a parameter.
 */
void WorkerThreadManager::PushResult(int A_result, result_function_t A_resultFun)
{
    utils::ScopedLock mutex(m_resultsMutex);

    signal_function_t signal = boost::bind(A_resultFun, A_result);
    m_results.push( signal );
}


/**
 * @brief   worker thread body
 * @param A_data pointer to WorkerThreadManager instance
 */
void* WorkerThreadManager::WorkerThread(void* A_data)
{
    WorkerThreadManager* manager = reinterpret_cast<WorkerThreadManager*>(A_data);
    LOG_DEBUG("Starting worker thread loop");
    while (1)
    {
        if ( -1 == sem_wait(&manager->m_tasksSem) && errno == EINTR )
        {
            LOG_DEBUG("sem_wait interrupted with signal");
            continue;
        }
        LOG_DEBUG("WorkerThread:::::: about to call lock mutex");

        worker_thread_data_t data;
        {
            utils::ScopedLock mutex(manager->m_tasksMutex);
            data = manager->m_tasks.front();
            manager->m_results.pop();
        }

        LOG_DEBUG("WorkerThread:::::: about to call resultFun");
        int result  = data.threadFun();
        LOG_DEBUG("WorkerThread:::::: after call resultFun");
        pthread_testcancel();

        manager->PushResult(result, data.resultFun);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "gateway_log.h"
#include "WorkerThreadManager.h"
#include <memory>

class A {
public:
    int Fun() { LOG_DEBUG("Fun before sleep"); sleep(8); LOG_DEBUG("Fun after sleep");return 0; }
    void Result(int a) { LOG_DEBUG("Result: " << a); }
};


int main()
{
    sd::auto_ptr<WorkerThreadManager> workerThreadManager = new WorkerThreadManager;
    A a;
    workerThreadManager->PushTask(boost::bind(&A::Fun, &a), boost::bind(&A::Result, &a, _1));
    sleep(3);
    LOG_DEBUG("deleting workerThreadManager");
    workerThreadManager.reset();                    // <<<--- CRASH
    LOG_DEBUG("deleted workerThreadManager");
    sleep(10);
    LOG_DEBUG("after sleep");    

    return 0;
}
```

GDB:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb7ad33a0 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x0807d3a7 in boost::function0<void>::clear (this=0x858db48) at /home/marcin/intel_build/boost_1_42_0/boost/function/function_template.hpp:856
#2  0x0807d17b in boost::function0<void>::~function0 (this=0x858db48, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /home/marcin/intel_build/boost_1_42_0/boost/function/function_template.hpp:752
#3  0x0807cec5 in boost::function<void()>::~function(void) (this=0x858db48, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /home/marcin/intel_build/boost_1_42_0/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1043
#4  0x0807ced8 in std::_Destroy<boost::function<void ()> >(boost::function<void ()>*) (__pointer=0x858db48) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_construct.h:94
#5  0x0807c868 in std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<boost::function<void ()>*>(boost::function<void ()>*, boost::function<void ()>*) (__first=0x858db48, __last=0x858d928) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_construct.h:104
#6  0x0807bd05 in std::_Destroy<boost::function<void ()>*>(boost::function<void ()>*, boost::function<void ()>*) (__first=0x858d938, __last=0x858d928) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_construct.h:127
#7  0x0807af23 in std::_Destroy<boost::function<void ()>*, boost::function<void ()> >(boost::function<void ()>*, boost::function<void ()>*, std::allocator<boost::function<void ()> >&) (__first=0x858d938, __last=0x858d928)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_construct.h:153
#8  0x0807a037 in std::deque<boost::function<void ()>, std::allocator<boost::function<void ()> > >::_M_destroy_data_aux(std::_Deque_iterator<boost::function<void ()>, boost::function<void ()>&, boost::function<void ()>*>, std::_Deque_iterator<boost::function<void ()>, boost::function<void ()>&, boost::function<void ()>*>) (this=0x858beec, __first=..., __last=...) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/deque.tcc:795
#9  0x08076153 in std::deque<boost::function<void ()>, std::allocator<boost::function<void ()> > >::_M_destroy_data(std::_Deque_iterator<boost::function<void ()>, boost::function<void ()>&, boost::function<void ()>*>, std::_Deque_iterator<boost::function<void ()>, boost::function<void ()>&, boost::function<void ()>*>, std::allocator<boost::function<void ()> > const&) (this=0x858beec, __first=..., __last=...) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_deque.h:1816
#10 0x08073411 in std::deque<boost::function<void()>, std::allocator<boost::function<void()> > >::~deque(void) (this=0x858beec, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_deque.h:898
#11 0x0806a355 in std::queue<boost::function<void()>, std::deque<boost::function<void()>, std::allocator<boost::function<void()> > > >::~queue(void) (this=0x858beec, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_queue.h:92
#12 0x0815a054 in WorkerThreadManager::~WorkerThreadManager (this=0x858be98, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at WorkerThreadManager.cpp:42
#13 0x0815a1e3 in WorkerThreadManager::~WorkerThreadManager (this=0x858be98, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at WorkerThreadManager.cpp:56
#14 0x080c6c51 in std::auto_ptr<WorkerThreadManager>::reset (this=0x85463e4, __p=0x0) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/backward/auto_ptr.h:244
#15 0x080604a9 in main ()
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a bug, it was trivial - shame on me :(

In function `void* WorkerThreadManager::WorkerThread(void* A_data)` I popped `m_results` queue instead of `m_tasks` as I had intended:

```
worker_thread_data_t data;
{
    utils::ScopedLock mutex(manager->m_tasksMutex);
    data = manager->m_tasks.front();
    manager->m_results.pop();
}
```

Anyway I don't really understand why it caused crash so late - in destructor of the queue.

Comment: Calling `pop()` from an empty queue is UB.  In this case, I suspect it's corrupting the internal structure, which becomes a problem when it attempts to clean up during destruction.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that `pthread_cancel` waits for the cancellation of the target completes before it returns.  When successful, it simply requests cancellation, but does not wait for it to complete.  You need to use `pthread_join` to wait for the threads to have completed.

I suspect that as the destructor is proceeding in one thread, one of the threads wakes up (due to the `sem_destroy`), and erroneously attempts to read/pop the queue.  I'm not sure why it's causing a crash in the main thread, but I would eliminate this potential issue first.

Finally, I would highly recommend you move some of these semaphore and thread mechanisms to their own classes, to make the code more exception safe.

Comment: In this example when pthread_cancel was called, worker thread was sleeping in function A::Fun. `sleep()` is a cancellation point, so all worker threads including the "busy" one exited immediately. This is why sem_destroy could not cause crash. Anyway I have corrected the code to inject empty boost::function to all worker threads to request exit and then to join these threads.

Comment: I don't understand why "some of these semaphore and thread mechanisms to their own classes" would make the code more exception safe? POSIX functions don't throw as they are implemented in C. My code throws in critical situations that can not be handled like thread creation - that's ok.

Comment: @Marcin:  Well, among other things:  If any of the pthread_creates fail, then you're failing to destroy those that remain.  Similar situation with destroying the semaphore, if an exception occurs in your constructor