# C++ kill method without constantly checking flags

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have several work functions, that call accessory functions that might have something bad happen. I want to be able to stop the work functions if an accessory function determines something bad happened, without putting numerous flag checks in the work functions. For example,

```
struct Worker {
    bool badhappened = false;
    Worker() {
        std::thread([&]() {
            while ( not badhappened );
            // kill the work
        }).detach();
    }
    int WorkComponent {
        if ( badhappening() )
            badhappened = true;
        return someint;
    }
    void DoWork {
        // WorkComponents called several times
    }
}
```

But I don't know what to call at `kill the work`. It's not a problem for `DoWork` to happen in a separate thread, but there doesn't appear to be an equivalent `pthread_kill` in C++'s threads. Is there a solution that doesn't involve putting several `if(badhappened) return;` calls into `DoWork`?

Comment: You could use Boost threads instead, as they have termination points that can be checked (which is not much different than checking a variable I admit). However, forcibly killing a thread might be bad, especially if the thread has allocated resources.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `pthread_kill`, to my knowledge, can send a similar termination signal that `kill` does. I imagine there's a similar mechanic in `std::thread`, just don't know what it is.

@MartinJames That could work actually, it shouldn't happen often enough to be a noticeable performance hit. Good idea, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately there are no such features in `std::thread`, but I hope it comes in the next C++ standard (whenever that comes). However, you can use the [`std::thread::native_handle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle) function to get the native pthread (hopefully) handle and then call `pthread_kill`.

Answer (score 6):

Long story short:

**There is no safe way to stop a non-cooperative thread.**

Yes, there are tools to forcibly shut down a thread but you are asking for trouble. The only safe way is to agree on a termination policy. This boils down to checking a flag sufficiently frequently as you write.

More on this from the gurus:

[C++ and Beyond 2011: Scott, Andrei and Herb - Ask Us Anything](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2011-Scott-Andrei-and-Herb-Ask-Us-Anything)

See at 30:44 What's the deal with systematic and principled thread termination and program termination?

---

Canceling a thread is not a good idea in POSIX either:

[Cancelling a thread using pthread_cancel : good practice or bad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4760687/341970)