# Terminate a thread that activates a process in the shell

Tags: c, shell, pthreads

Using pthreads, I created a thread that does audio recording through shell:

```
void *thread_function(void *arg) {

system("arecord data.wav");

}
```

However, when I call `pthread_cancel(&thread_ID);` to terminate the thread, the audio recorder still works on its own (Until I terminate the whole C program of course).

How do I stop a pthread that does a system call? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
system("arecord data.wav");
```

It will make a separate process (not a thread in your program) in your system, and terminating that thread will not affect that process. You should kill that process by another system call.

However making the process with [spawn*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spawn_%28computing%29) functions in non-waiting mode is a bit better than your way and in this case and you don't need an extra thread.

```
spawnl(P_NOWAIT, "arecord data.wav", .... );
```

But, killing the created process is ugly.

Comment: Seems logical. So I'll have to instead make a `system("killall arecord");`?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04. Anyways, just tested the `killall` method and it worked for me. Seems I won't have to use pthreads after all. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: False alarm: At first I tried the `killall` thing with the threads mechanism. Without it, the program is stuck in the system call. So in essence, threads are still necessary.

Comment: This answer is not sound advice. The point of calling `system` from a new thread is that your program can continue running while `system` blocks. However, `system` has lots of underlying thread-safety issues that make its use a very bad idea. Using `fork` and `exec` or better yet `posix_spawn` would be better. If you want a pthread-style interface, you can wrap it in a thread that calls `posix_spawn` then immediately calls `waitpid`, and the thread can have a cancellation function that kills the child process so that `pthread_cancel` can be used on it.

Comment: @MM.: That's even worse. Then you have no pid for the child process and thus no way to determine when it's finished or to kill it early.

Comment: AFAIK `arecord` is stopped by killing the process (CTRL+Z). The output .wav is fine and not corrupted. So I'm not worried of killing it, unless there's something about `arecord`'s control abilities I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Your thread start function should do the following:

```
pid_t pid;
int status;
posix_spawnp(&pid, "arecord", 0, 0, (char *[]){"arecord", "data.wav", 0}, environ);
pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup, &pid);
while (waitpid(pid, &status, 0)<0 && errno==EINTR);
pthread_cleanup_pop(0);
```

With a cleanup function like:

```
static void cleanup(void *p)
{
    pid_t pid = *(pid_t *)p;
    kill(pid, SIGTERM);
    while (waitpid(pid, &status, 0)<0 && errno==EINTR);
}
```

Then cancelling the thread with `pthread_cancel` will kill the child process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pthread_kill` to send a signal to a specific thread.  The problem with thread cancellation is that it will be delayed until the program reaches a cancellation point ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760687/cancelling-a-thread-using-pthread-cancel-good-practice-or-bad)).

If you do use `pthread_kill` then you can choose which signal to send.  I think it should be possible to end the thread with a kill signal which would then also end the child process spawned with system, although I'm not certain about that.

Comment: Nope, it didn't do the trick. I think it's as M M. says. Anyways, thank you for your help! `:)`