# Using a thread in C++ to report progress of computations

Tags: c++, unix, pthreads

I'm writing a generic abstract class to be able to report on the status of as many instance variables as we need. For instance, consider the following useless loop:

```
int a, b;
for (int i=0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j < 1000; ++j) {
        for (int k =0; k < 1000; ++k) {
            a = i;
            b = j;
        }
    }
}
```

It would be nice to be able to see the values of `a` and `b` without having to modify the loop. In the past I have written if statements such as the following:

```
int a, b;
for (int i=0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j < 1000; ++j) {
        for (int k =0; k < 1000; ++k) {
            a = i;
            b = j;
            if (a % 100 == 0) {
                printf("a = %d\n", a);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This would allow me to see the value of `a` every 100 iterations. However, depending on the computations being done, sometimes it is just not possible to check on the progress in this fashion. The idea is to have be able to go away from the computer, come back after a given time and check on whatever values you want to see.

To this end we can use `pthreads`. The following code works, and the only reason I am posting it is because I'm not sure if I'm using the thread correctly, mainly, how to shut it off.

First lets consider the file "reporter.h":

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>

void* run_reporter(void*);

class reporter {
public: 
    pthread_t thread;
    bool stdstream;
    FILE* fp;

    struct timespec sleepTime;
    struct timespec remainingSleepTime;

    const char* filename;
    const int sleepT;
    double totalTime;

    reporter(int st, FILE* fp_): fp(fp_), filename(NULL), stdstream(true), sleepT(st) {
        begin_report();
    }
    reporter(int st, const char* fn): fp(NULL), filename(fn), stdstream(false), sleepT(st) {
        begin_report();
    }
    void begin_report() {
        totalTime = 0;
        if (!stdstream) fp = fopen(filename, "w");
        fprintf(fp, "reporting every %d seconds ...\n", sleepT);
        if (!stdstream) fclose(fp);
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, run_reporter, this);
    }
    void sleep() {
        sleepTime.tv_sec=sleepT;
        sleepTime.tv_nsec=0;
        nanosleep(&sleepTime, &remainingSleepTime);
        totalTime += sleepT;
    }
    virtual void report() = 0;
    void end_report() {
        pthread_cancel(thread);
        // Wrong addition of remaining time, needs to be fixed
        // but non-important at the moment.
        //totalTime += sleepT - remainingSleepTime.tv_sec;
        long sec = remainingSleepTime.tv_sec;
        if (!stdstream) fp = fopen(filename, "a");
        fprintf(fp, "reported for %g seconds.\n", totalTime);
        if (!stdstream) fclose(fp);
    }
};

void* run_reporter(void* rep_){
    reporter* rep = (reporter*)rep_;
    while(1) {
        if (!rep->stdstream) rep->fp = fopen(rep->filename, "a");
        rep->report();
        if (!rep->stdstream) fclose(rep->fp);
        rep->sleep();
    }
}
```

This file declares the abstract class `reporter`, notice the pure virtual function `report`. This is the function that will print the messages. Each reporter has its own `thread` and the thread gets created when the `reporter` constructor is called. To use the `reporter` object in our useless loop now we can do:

```
#include "reporter.h"
int main() {
    // Declaration of objects we want to track
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    // Declaration of reporter
    class prog_reporter: public reporter {
    public:
        int& a;
        int& b;
        prog_reporter(int& a_, int& b_):
            a(a_), b(b_),
            reporter(3, stdout)
        {}
        void report() {
            fprintf(fp, "(a, b) = (%d, %d)\n", this->a, this->b);
        }
    };
    // Start tracking a and b every 3 seconds
    prog_reporter rep(a, b);

    // Do some useless computation
    for (int i=0; i < 10000; ++i) {
        for (int j=0; j < 1000; ++j) {
            for (int k =0; k < 1000; ++k) {
                a = i;
                b = j;
            }
        }
    }
    // Stop reporting
    rep.end_report();
}
```

After compiling this code (no optimization flag) and running it I obtain:

```
macbook-pro:Desktop jmlopez$ g++ testing.cpp
macbook-pro:Desktop jmlopez$ ./a.out 
reporting every 3 seconds ...
(a, b) = (0, 60)
(a, b) = (1497, 713)
(a, b) = (2996, 309)
(a, b) = (4497, 478)
(a, b) = (5996, 703)
(a, b) = (7420, 978)
(a, b) = (8915, 78)
reported for 18 seconds.
```

This does exactly what I wanted it to do, with the optimization flags then I get:

```
macbook-pro:Desktop jmlopez$ g++ testing.cpp -O3
macbook-pro:Desktop jmlopez$ ./a.out 
reporting every 3 seconds ...
(a, b) = (0, 0)
reported for 0 seconds.
```

Which is not surprising since the compiler probably rewrote my the code to give me the same answer in a shorter amount of time. My original question was going to be why the reporter did not give me the values of the variables if I made the loops longer, for instance:

```
for (int i=0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j < 100000; ++j) {
        for (int k =0; k < 100000; ++k) {
            a = i;
            b = j;
        }
    }
}
```

After running the code again with the optimization flag:

```
macbook-pro:Desktop jmlopez$ g++ testing.cpp -O3
macbook-pro:Desktop jmlopez$ ./a.out 
reporting every 3 seconds ...
(a, b) = (0, 0)
(a, b) = (0, 0)
(a, b) = (0, 0)
(a, b) = (0, 0)
(a, b) = (0, 0)
(a, b) = (0, 0)
(a, b) = (0, 0)
(a, b) = (0, 0)
(a, b) = (0, 0)
(a, b) = (0, 0)
(a, b) = (0, 0)
(a, b) = (0, 0)
(a, b) = (0, 0)
(a, b) = (0, 0)
reported for 39 seconds.
```

**Question:** Is this output due to the optimization flag which modifies the code and it simply decides not to update the variables til the very end?

### Main question:

In the `reporter` method `end_report` I call the function `pthread_cancel`. After reading the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4760758/788553) it made me doubtful about the use of the function and how I was terminating the reporting thread. For those experienced with `pthreads`, is there any obvious holes or potential problems using the `thread` as I have done?

Comment: The main issue you face is that the "useless loop" and the reporter access `a` and `b` concurrently without synchonisation/protection. The reporter can not be sure it reads out the "real" values of `a` and `b`. Those could just be placed in registers for example, as the compiler has no idea the reporter wants to read them at a certain time. Concurrent access shall be protected. Have a look at mutexts to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the main question: You're close. Add a call to `pthread_join()` (http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_join) after `pthread_cancel()`, and everything should be fine.

The join call makes sure that you clean up the threads resources, and, if forgotten, can lead to running out of threading resources in certain cases.

And just to add, the important point when using `pthread_cancel()` (apart from remembering to join the thread) is to make sure that the thread you are canceling has a so-called [cancellation point](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html), which your thread does by calling `nanosleep()` (and possibly also `fopen`, `fprintf` and `fclose` which *may* be cancellation points). If no cancellation point exists, your thread will just keep running.

Comment: What would the arguments to `pthread_join` be? I assume the first one is the thread object which was just cancelled. But I'm clueless about the second one. In the documentation it says to use `PTHREAD_CANCELED` as the second argument but this not of type `void**`.

Comment: The first argument is just the thread object, whereas the second argument is used to obtain the return value of your thread (mainly for use when you don't cancel the thread, but instead let the thread run until it completes - if a thread is canceled, the value stored in retval will be that of `PTHREAD_CANCELED`). Just set it to `NULL` in your case, which will cause `pthread_join()` to ignore it.

Comment: got it, so simply add `pthread_join(thread, NULL);` right after `pthread_cancel`.

Comment: To explicitly add a cancellation point to a thread's code, let it call `pthread_testcancel()`.

Answer (score 3):

C++ doesn't know about threads and your code uses two local variables `a` and `b` and makes no call to a function with unknown code.

What happens is that `a` and `b` end up in registers **during the loop** for the computation and they're updated only at the end of the loop.

While it's true that `a` and `b` must get a real memory address (because they've been passed as reference to an external function) the compiler doesn't know that some external code that knows the address of `a` and `b` will execute **during** the loop, and thus prefers to store all intermediate values to registers until the loop ends.

If your code in the loop however calls an unknown function (i.e. a function for which the implementation is not known) then the compiler will be forced to update `a` and `b` before calling the function because it must be paranoid and consider that the progress function that got passed the address of `a` and `b` may pass this information to the unknown function.

Comment: Just to clarify, this happens when using the optimization flag right?

Comment: I also think that what the op is trying to do makes sense only with an async approach or when you have a pool of threads ( with a special queue ), in this case I see almost no benefits in doing this.

Comment: Well, to say in 2013 that "C++ doesn't know about threads" is a tad outdated, isn't it? What actually happens here is that it is simply UB nowadays to do this without proper synchronization, isn't it?

Comment: @MartinBa, excuse my lack of acronyms but what does UB stand for?

Comment: @jmlopez UB stands for "undefined behaviour" and is the C++ standard's term for saying that the compiler might do *anything* with such code -- including producing an expected result as it were. C++11 introduced threading and a memoy model and under this model concurrently accessing non-synchronized state from multiple threads is UB.

Comment: @MartinBa, ah, got it.

Comment: @MartinBa: afaik the C++ compiler today knows exactly what was knowing before, i.e. it simply ignores threads in that kind of code. The **standard library** now has thread support however (when before instead you had to wrap pthreads on *x and windows calls in a non-standard library to get portable threaded code).

Comment: @6502 You're rigth in that regard, I guess. One should emphazize that without synchronization it would also be possible to get totally bogus and/or inconsistent values for a and b.