# set execution time of a c++ code beforehand

Tags: c++, shell, time, c++14, execution

I want a C++ code to run for a specific amount of time and complete a statement before ending the execution. For example, consider the following scenario regarding the execution of a program:

> Initialise a counter with 0. If the execution time is equal to x milliseconds then print the current value of the counter, else increment the counter by 1.

The above task might be accomplished by writing a C++ code something like:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int c=0;
    while(true){
        /* do something to check the execution time, 
        if it is equal to x milliseconds print the value of c and exit*/

        c++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

***Actually, I want to compare two optimization algorithms implemented in C++ for a particular problem based on how much optimal solution they can give if executed for the same amount of time.***

I searched on the Internet, but could not get what I actually want. It looks like thread based solutions are there, but I don't want threads to be involved unless it is extremely necessary. It is favourable if the problem can be solved by some C++ features alone, but it is okay if some shell script to invoke the C++ code would do the trick (I am likely to run the codes on Linux system). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What have you done so far (apart from describing your homework) and where are you stuck?

Comment: Are you looking for ways to [report progress of computation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586968/using-a-thread-in-c-to-report-progress-of-computations)

Comment: `#include <chrono>`

Comment: You could try the magic of Qt's slots and signals too: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

Comment: @xxbbcc: I have written the programs which are working fine, and now I want them to run for a specific amount of time and then print some result before exiting. Do you want me to include the gigantic codes in the question? I can do so, but I don't think that is necessary (at least after I have provided a demo code which represents my intention perfectly).

Comment: @Matsmath: Not exactly.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Do you mean the second approach mentioned by 
gg.kaspersky?

Comment: @DYangu: I'll try that if I can't do without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about good old [alarms](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/alarm.2.html) and [signals](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html)?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void catchAlarm(int sig) {
    std::cerr << "You will now die, Mr Bond!!\n";
    exit(-1);
}

int main(){
    int c=0;

    // Die in 2 seconds....
    signal(SIGALRM, catchAlarm);
    alarm(2); 

    while(true){
        /* do something to check the execution time, 
        if it is equal to x milliseconds print the value of c and exit*/
        c++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**:  the boilerplate code above does not allow you to print any of the internal state, however since you are using C++14 you can simply capture that in a closure, and then use the closure to dig into the internals, like

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>    
using namespace std;

std::function<void()> myClosure; // The closure needs to be accessible to the alarm-function
void catchAlarm(int sig) {
    myClosure();
    exit(-1);
}

int main(){
    int c=0;

    myClosure = [&]()->void{
       std::cerr << "You will now die at age " << c << "\n";
    };

    // Die in 2 seconds....
    signal(SIGALRM, catchAlarm);
    alarm(2);

    while(true){
        /* do something to check the execution time, 
        if it is equal to x milliseconds print the value of c and exit*/    
        c++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However (and this may be a big however or small one depending on your case), signals are triggered by the kernel, and it may execute at any time, including while half way through code which the compiler was executing sequentially, but now are not as your alarm interrupted it halfway though. In your case where your just print stuff, you may be fine as worst case would be some funny output, but if your lambda is modifying any object you may end up with problems that resemble that of non-thread safe code.

Comment: This looks like what I was looking for! Just 2 points : 1. The header `alarm.h` does not work, I had to include `unistd.h` and `signal.h`,  2. Can I make the function `catchAlarm` to print the latest value of `c` without making `c` a global variable?

Comment: Sure, since you are using C++14, you can capture the interesting stuff in a lambda function and then call that from the signal handler, added an example above -- note that if you are using gnu g++ you need to pass   `g++ -std=c++14`  (or -std=c++11) as an option before lambda function are enabled

Comment: What you are allowed to do in a signal handler is extremely limited. Calling a `std::function` is not one of them; nor is printing to `std::cerr`.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [timeout(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout).

If you'd rather do it in C++ (I think the script solution is better -- let programs do one thing and do it well unless the you're extremely resource-constrained) then the classical UNIX solution is [alarm(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm) (which timeout could be based on, though there are a couple newer timers).

If you'll want to do something other than have the program die after the timeout expires, then you'll need to setup a handler for the `SIGALRM` signal.

Comment: `timeout` actually does not meet the requirements as I want some job to be done before ending the program (as you correctly pointed out in your last statement). `alarm` seems perfect.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution for your problem requires more insight on how exactly your code is organized and how exactly you perform the computation. Here is a possible solution:

Move your computation code to run in a separate thread. You can use `<thread>` to create threads. Pass an addional flag argument to the computation thread, or just make it global (e.g. `std::atomic<bool> time_s_up`). Your code should look like:

```
void compute(std::atomic<bool> &time_is_up)
{
    while (!time_is_up) {
        c++;
    }
}
```

In the main thread, after you start your thread, you can use a sleep or timer, after which you do:

```
int main()
{
    std::atomic<bool> time_s_up = false;
    std::thread t(compute, time_s_up);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    time_s_up = true;
    t.join();
}
```

Another solution (the one you actually thought of) is also good, but only when the `c++` statements are more complex computations, so the calls to get the time would represent only a slight overhead:

```
// auto g_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
// g_time - total number of milliseconds to run
while (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - g_start).count() <= g_time) {
    some_complex_iteration_computations();
}
```

If you use another approach, (like `timeout` or alarms as suggested by other answers), then you'll have to somehow keep track of partial results, because the kill signal will just terminate your program without getting a chance to print the current result.

Comment: I'll try these solutions if I can't do without them. I am bit reluctant to use threads.

Comment: Threads are not a problem. I just want to avoid more complexities since the codes themselves are already complex.

Comment: Also, it is not clear to me how I can print the latest value of `c` (in this case) if I use threads.

Comment: @SnehasishKarmakar, just add a print statement after ```while(!time_is_up)``` loop

Answer (score 0):

`alarm` is a cool solution.

Here I provide a stupid but easy solution.

```
// c code
int main(int argc, char ** argv[]) {
    for (int i = 1; ; ++i) {
        // do something
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

then run program by this way.

```
#!/bin/bash
./a.out &
sleep 2s && kill $(jobs -p)
```

Comment: I don't need exactly this. I want the program to print the latest result once just before exiting (upon exceeding the given time limit).

Comment: @SnehasishKarmakar just add | tail -1