# pthread_cancel and cancellation point

Tags: linux, multithreading

I'm learning the pthread_cancel function and testing whether thread would be cancelled when it doesn't reach cancellation point. Thread is created by default attribute and make it running in add loop. But when cancellation request was sent and thread exit immediately. It doesn't reach cancellation point and I think it should not respond to the request immediately.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *thread_func(void *arg)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;

    k = 1;

    /* add operation */
    for (i=0; i<1000; ++i) {       
        for (j=0; j<10000;++j) {
             ++k;              // maybe for(z=0; z<10000; ++z) added would 
                               // be better
        }
    }
    return (void *)10;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *retval;
    pthread_t tid;

    if (pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_func, NULL) != 0) {                 
        printf("create error\n");
    }

    if (pthread_cancel(tid) != 0) { // cancel thread
        printf("cancel error\n");
    }
    pthread_join(tid, (void **)retval); 
    printf("main thread exit\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm just finding that the add loop will complete immediately without request and maybe it's not a good test.

Comment: Don't use `pthread_cancel`.  For a starter on why, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760687/cancelling-a-thread-using-pthread-cancel-good-practice-or-bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a "cancellation point" you need to use `pthread_setcancelstate()` to disable cancellation at the start of your thread function and then enable it when you want.  When a new thread is spawned, it has the cancel state "enabled" meaning it can be canceled immediately at any time.

Perhaps more to the point, you probably shouldn't use `pthread_cancel()` at all.  For more on that, see here: [Cancelling a thread using pthread_cancel : good practice or bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760687/cancelling-a-thread-using-pthread-cancel-good-practice-or-bad)

Comment: Yeah, thanks. And I'm testing the property of pthread_cancel.  Maybe this function is not a good choice indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Cancelling a thread never means that it will immediately cancel anything which is running. It would just post a request to that thread. pthread_cancel only cancels a thread at a cancellation point. The list of cancellation points are defined in the man page of `pthreads`. In the above thread, you don't have any code which is a cancellation point. So the thread will always complete and will never get canceled. You can increase the loop or put a print statement at the last line of your thread and you will see that it is always completing the thread.

But, if you change the below code to add `usleep` (it is one of the cancellation point as defined in the man pages), you can see that the thread terminates after `usleep`. Even if you run any number of times, the thread will only get terminated at the cancellation point that is immediately after `usleep` and not any other point.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *thread_func(void *arg)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;

    k = 1;

    /* add operation */
    for (i=0; i<1000; ++i) {
        printf("Before - %d\n", i);
        usleep(1);
        printf("After - %d\n", i);
        for (j=0; j<10000;++j) {
             ++k;              // maybe for(z=0; z<10000; ++z) added would
                               // be better
        }
        printf("Never - %d\n", i);
    }
    printf("Normal Exit of thread\n");
    return (void *)10;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *retval;
    pthread_t tid;

    if (pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_func, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("create error\n");
    }

    usleep(1000);
    if (pthread_cancel(tid) != 0) { // cancel thread
        printf("cancel error\n");
    }
    pthread_join(tid, (void **)retval);
    printf("main thread exit\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thread you created actually didn't get cancelled. You can see this by examining the return value of `pthread_join()`. A return value of `PTHREAD_CANCELED` signals that the thread was cancelled:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *thread_func(void *arg)
{
    long k = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
            k++;

    return (void *)k;
}

int main(void)
{
    void *retval;
    pthread_t tid;

    if (pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_func, NULL) != 0)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    if (pthread_cancel(tid) != 0)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    if (pthread_join(tid, &retval) != 0)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    if (retval == PTHREAD_CANCELED)
        printf("thread cancelled\n");
    else
        printf("thread exited normally (k=%ld)\n", (long)retval);

    printf("main thread exit\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Running the program shows the following output:

```
thread exited normally (k=100000000)
main thread exit
```

As you can see from the above output, the thread simply completed its job and returned normally (indeed, the thread doesn't contain any cancellation points to cancel at). It just did it so quickly that you assumed it was cancelled. Increasing the iteration count (to, for example, `i = j = 100000`) makes it more obvious that the thread is not being cancelled.

You can explicitly add a cancellation point with `pthread_testcancel()`, and the thread will cancel as expected:

```
void *thread_func(void *arg)
{
    long k = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++) {
            k++;
            pthread_testcancel(); // Add cancellation point here
        }
    }

    return (void *)k;
}
```

The program now exits immediately with the following output:

```
thread cancelled
main thread exit
```